# How to call code inside ngAfterViewInit again in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

In my angular component I have `ngAfterViewInit` method which contains some statements that I want to execute after the view is initialized cause it contains some DOM manupulations.

My question is when some parameter is changed I want to run the code inside `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Just move the code to another method that you call from `ngAfterViewInit` and wherever else you want.

Comment: That code gives me error if the component is not initialized. That's why I put it inside ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Maybe this [plunkr example helps](https://embed.plnkr.co/XVMd1oQfI3IjRYTkG9li/)

Comment: Please post the code that causes the error and the error message.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the code uses d3 to draw graph.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute those statements on every changes than it is better to write those in `ngAfterViewChecked()`.From [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked):

> A lifecycle hook that is called after the default change detector has completed checking a component's view for changes
>
> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has completed one change-check cycle for a component's view.

So it will be called on every subsequent changes.

More information can also be found on the [Lifecycle Hooks#AfterView](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) docs

Answer (score 3):

You could define an `EventEmitter` in the constructor, subscribe to it in the `ngAfterViewInit()` function to update those values, emit it in the `ngAfterViewInit()` function, and then emit it again every single time you want to call it in subsequent areas of the component. Here is an example:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public myEvent: EventEmitter<void>;
  
  public constructor() {
    this.myEvent = new EventEmitter<void>();
  }
  
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // This is how you call the function to do what you want to do with your DOM manipulations below. You can also call this exact function even from the HTML, if you wish to do so (see HTML example).
    this.myEvent.emit();
    
    this.myEvent.subscribe(
      () => {
        // Do whatever actions that you need to do here to perform your DOM manipulations.
      },
      (err: Error) => console.error(err);
    );
  }
  
  public emitMyEvent(): void {
    this.myEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

```html
<my-component (click)="myEvent.emit()"></my-component>

<!-- or -->

<my-component (click)="emitMyEvent()"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your parameter is available as an Observable, you can just subscribe to it in the `ngAfterViewInit`method. If your parameter is not yet available as Observable, I suggest you take a look at the [BehaviourSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) class. With this, you can control when the Observable will emit a new value + It will be triggered with the last value when you subscribe to it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, As I was not subscribing my Observable in the ngAfterViewInit() (bcoz- I was using async pipe in template to directly render latest data from server) so my template was not getting updated result.

Answer (score 1):

You declare ordinary class methords in the class body, and later define them in the context of ngAfterviewInit.
here's a simple use case example:

```
export class ViewtestComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('someElementMewantedToDoAction') elRef: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  changeVal; 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeVal= (useME) => {
      // some action
      this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText++;
    }
   }
```

Later, use the method in template as

```
// Do Action=  Button value will increment 11, 12 13 ... on each button   click.

<button class="button success" (click)="changeVal($emit)>10</button>
```

Comment: Using function expression insted of function declaration inside ngAfterViewInit() work well.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by implementing `OnChanges` and call `ngAfterviewInit` for changes other than the firstchange.This way I will make sure that the view is initiallized. By the way the variable subjected to change(changed_var) holds data used in DOM manipulation.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(!changes.changed_var.isFirstChange()){
        this.ngAfterViewInit();
    }
}
```